# My IF statement work only for my last i value in a FOR in C# WinForm .NET

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently studying programming, I am learning C#. I am creating a login and registration system.

My problem is that for my password when registering, I'm trying to make a dynamic form that shows what the password has, doesn't have.

I created a function when my TextBox changes, the function works fine but only on the last pass in my strong loop. If my password contains everything that is requested, it is only the IF of my last character that turns the condition green.

I attach images and code if needed.

The C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjetMadeInValDeLoir
{
    public partial class Inscription : Form
    {
        public Inscription()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void inputMotDePasse_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initialisation variable et récupération mot de passe

            string motDePasseValue;
            string possibleCharactereMin;
            string possibleCharactereMaj;
            string possibleCharactereChiffre;
            string possibleCharactereSpecial;

            bool minExiste;
            bool majExiste;
            bool chiffreExiste;
            bool charSpecialExiste;
            bool min12Characters;

            minExiste = false;
            majExiste = false;
            chiffreExiste = false;
            charSpecialExiste = false;
            min12Characters = false;

            possibleCharactereMin = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            possibleCharactereMaj = possibleCharactereMin.ToLower();
            possibleCharactereChiffre = "0123456789";
            possibleCharactereSpecial = "~@_/#?!";
            motDePasseValue = inputMotDePasse.Text;

            // Vérification

            for (int i = 0; i < motDePasseValue.Count(); i++)
            {
                
                if (possibleCharactereMin.Contains(motDePasseValue[i]))
                {
                     minExiste = true;
                    min.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                } 
                else
                {
                    min.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
                if (possibleCharactereMaj.Contains(motDePasseValue[i]))
                {
                     majExiste = true;
                    maj.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    maj.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
                if (possibleCharactereChiffre.Contains(motDePasseValue[i]))
                {
                     chiffreExiste = true;
                    chiffre.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    chiffre.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
                if (possibleCharactereSpecial.Contains(motDePasseValue[i]))
                {
                     charSpecialExiste = true;
                    charSpecial.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    charSpecial.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
                charactere.Text = motDePasseValue;
            }

            if (motDePasseValue.Count() >= 12)
            {
                min12Characters = true;
                charactere.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The C# designer file:

```
namespace ProjetMadeInValDeLoir
{
    partial class Inscription
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.inputMotDePasse = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.maj = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.min = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.chiffre = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.charSpecial = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.charactere = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 134);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(209, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(110, 47);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.label1.Text = "Inscription";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 118);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label2.Text = "Pseudo";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 186);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(26, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 8;
            this.label3.Text = "Mail";
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 202);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(209, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 254);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 13);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 10;
            this.label4.Text = "Mot de passe";
            // 
            // inputMotDePasse
            // 
            this.inputMotDePasse.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 270);
            this.inputMotDePasse.Name = "inputMotDePasse";
            this.inputMotDePasse.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(209, 20);
            this.inputMotDePasse.TabIndex = 9;
            this.inputMotDePasse.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.inputMotDePasse_TextChanged);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Enabled = false;
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 468);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(209, 36);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 11;
            this.button2.Text = "Confirmer mon inscription";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this.label5.AutoSize = true;
            this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(57, 407);
            this.label5.Name = "label5";
            this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 13);
            this.label5.TabIndex = 13;
            this.label5.Text = "Retaper votre mot de passe";
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this.textBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 423);
            this.textBox4.Name = "textBox4";
            this.textBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(209, 20);
            this.textBox4.TabIndex = 12;
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 293);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(216, 13);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 14;
            this.label6.Text = "Votre mot de passe doit comporter au moins:";
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this.label7.AutoSize = true;
            this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 315);
            this.label7.Name = "label7";
            this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
            this.label7.TabIndex = 15;
            // 
            // maj
            // 
            this.maj.AutoSize = true;
            this.maj.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 328);
            this.maj.Name = "maj";
            this.maj.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 13);
            this.maj.TabIndex = 16;
            this.maj.Text = "• Une majuscule";
            // 
            // min
            // 
            this.min.AutoSize = true;
            this.min.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 341);
            this.min.Name = "min";
            this.min.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 13);
            this.min.TabIndex = 17;
            this.min.Text = "• Une minuscule";
            // 
            // chiffre
            // 
            this.chiffre.AutoSize = true;
            this.chiffre.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 354);
            this.chiffre.Name = "chiffre";
            this.chiffre.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(62, 13);
            this.chiffre.TabIndex = 18;
            this.chiffre.Text = "• Un chiffre";
            // 
            // charSpecial
            // 
            this.charSpecial.AutoSize = true;
            this.charSpecial.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 367);
            this.charSpecial.Name = "charSpecial";
            this.charSpecial.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(204, 13);
            this.charSpecial.TabIndex = 19;
            this.charSpecial.Text = "• Un caractère spécial (~, @, _, /, #, ?, !)";
            // 
            // charactere
            // 
            this.charactere.AutoSize = true;
            this.charactere.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 315);
            this.charactere.Name = "charactere";
            this.charactere.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 13);
            this.charactere.TabIndex = 20;
            this.charactere.Text = "• 12 charactères";
            // 
            // Inscription
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(355, 620);
            this.Controls.Add(this.charactere);
            this.Controls.Add(this.charSpecial);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chiffre);
            this.Controls.Add(this.min);
            this.Controls.Add(this.maj);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.inputMotDePasse);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Inscription";
            this.Text = "Inscription";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox inputMotDePasse;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label maj;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label min;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label chiffre;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label charSpecial;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label charactere;
    }
}
```

Edit and add different variable

Comment: Did you already use the debugger to step through your loop code step by step?

Comment: I would recommend creating a list of your character classes, possibly by introducing a custom type. Lists of repeated if-statements is often a code smell, indicating that there are better ways to implement it.

Comment: Why are you defining ```possibleCharactereMaj``` by taking the lower-case character string already defined and calling ```.ToLower()``` on it? Surely you meant ```.ToUpper()```? Also, why did you not use ```char.IsSymbol``` and similar instead of trying to define all possible characters and assign them a type (upper-case, lower-case, symbol, number)? All these exist in C# for you already. You just need a ```char``` reference and you can call the appropriate function to make the determinations you need.

Comment: @KlausGütter It's right, I find the problem with using the breakpoint... Thank !

Comment: @majixin Yeah, I didn't understand why I reversed the two and I hadn't even noticed that it was a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an improvement, it uses Linq to look for any of the matching characters in the test string.

```
namespace ProjetMadeInValDeLoir
{
    public partial class Inscription : Form
    {
        private readonly string possibleCharactereMin = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        private readonly string possibleCharactereMaj = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        private readonly string possibleCharactereChiffre = "0123456789";
        private readonly string possibleCharactereSpecial = "~@_/#?!";

        public Inscription()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void inputMotDePasse_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Vérification
            min.ForeColor = inputMotDePasse.Text.Any(c => possibleCharactereMin.Contains(c)) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            maj.ForeColor = inputMotDePasse.Text.Any(c => possibleCharactereMaj.Contains(c)) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            chiffre.ForeColor = inputMotDePasse.Text.Any(c => possibleCharactereChiffre.Contains(c)) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            charSpecial.ForeColor = inputMotDePasse.Text.Any(c => possibleCharactereSpecial.Contains(c)) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            charactere.ForeColor = inputMotDePasse.Text.Length >= 12 ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I did not know this method and is more optimal, better organized and above all, functional. Thank you so much !